# Django save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert' error

Tags: django, save

I'm getting a `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'` error. From this `http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/2471efd68d56ad59` it looks like the answer is to use:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
... 
   super(SiteUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My question is how would you go about specifying `force_insert=True` or `force_insert=False` when doing that.

My code is:

```
   def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
      if not self.id:
         self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.updated_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.description_html = markdown(self.description)
      self.highlighted_code = self.highlight()
      super(Snippet, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kwargs` is a `dict`. Set it as you would any other dict value.

```
kwargs['force_insert'] = True
```

Comment: I can see that working if you want to override the value, but how would you just specify it as a default value as in my code?

Comment: Changed my code to:    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      if not 'force_insert' in kwargs:
         kwargs['force_insert'] = False
      if not 'force_update' in kwargs:
         kwargs['force_update'] = False
      if not self.id:
         self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.updated_date = datetime.datetime.now()
      self.description_html = markdown(self.description)
      self.highlighted_code = self.highlight()
      super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
But still getting the same error. Is force_insert no longer supported in Django 1.3.1 or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert' even if I do a del kwargs['force_insert'] instead of adding. And that's the only place I'm doing anything with force_insert according to grep.